# What does this error mean when I try to run a .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to run this .kv file in VSCode, I've installed Kivy and KivyLang and added kv to the code runner file extensions list:

`".kv": "kivy"`

This is what I have in the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<MyGrid>
    Label:
        text:"s"
```

Is it because the executor file I have listed is wrong? if so what is the correct one, I just guessed because I didn't know and couldn't find anything on google about it.

edit: this is the error, i forgot to include it lol..

```
kivy : The term 'kivy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify  
that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ kivy "c:\Users\DELL-x\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Python\A-OTHER ...
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (kivy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: @Grismar Sorry I forgot to include it. I made an edit and the error is in the post now

Comment: You cannot execute a `kv` file. Have a look at the kivy [getting started](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/intro.html).